# $this->table() Throws [InvalidArgumentException] A row must be an array or a TableSeparator instance

Tags: laravel, symfony, command-line, laravel-4

I've written a L4 Command class but the `table` output is throwing an exception.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;

class Table extends Command {

    protected $name = 'table';

    public function fire()
    {
        //output table;
        $header = ['Name', 'Email', 'Age'];
        $row = ['Luke', 'me@email.uk', '99'];

        $this->info(sprintf("is array ? %s", is_array($row) ? 'true' : 'false'));
        //outputs is array ? true
        $this->table($header, $row);
        //throws exception
        // [InvalidArgumentException]
        // A row must be an array or a TableSeparator instance.

    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to pass in an array of rows. Per `table` definition:

```
void table(array $headers, array $rows, string $style = 'default')
```

So you either do

```
$row = [['Luke', 'me@email.uk', '99']]; // An array of arrays, containing one row
```

or

```
$this->table($header, [$row]);
```

Comment: Thanks opted for `$row[] = ['Luke', 'me@email.uk', '99]` as that seemed slightly more readable. Not sure why it doesn't complain about the `$headers` array though if the signature is the same.... ?

Comment: Because the error is thrown further down the chain in an `addRow` method. There is only one header but multiple rows. Check the logs for a full stacktrace.